# Distribute 5 red balls and 5 blue balls into three distinct boxes

Tags: combinatorics

So if I was just doing them separately there would be 21 ways or 7 choose 5 ways. Do i just multiply it then 21 * 21? Unsure how to put them together.

Comment: distinct or indistinguishable balls?

Comment: the balls are identical while the boxes are distinguishable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the balls are distinct then choose one from three boxes for each ball.

If the balls are indistinguishable (aside from colour) then count ways to arrange *two* partitions and *five* red objects.  Do the same for five blue objects. Multiply.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly calculated the number of ways to put 5 red indistinguishable balls into 3 distinguishable boxes.

Same for 5 blue balls.

There is an obvious 1-to-1 relation between "combination of 5 blue and 5 red balls" and a pair ("combination of red balls", "combination of blue balls"). So 21 * 21 is the answer.